# Documentation Topics does not have introduction section

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

A Topic have current sections as of now

```
Topic Name 
Examples    
Syntax
Remarks
```

In my opinion, one thing is missing : `Introduction` about topic.

Currently you can enter one line for `Topic Name`. Later you can't provide preface or introduction about the topic.

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/1720/decorator-pattern#t=201608091822491646176

In this `Decorator-Pattern` topic, if we have some section like `preface` or `introduction` after topic name, it will cover basic information about that topic such as Structure or Architecture.

In above example, we can provide UML diagram or structure of the pattern in that new section and leave `Examples` section dedicated to code examples. In absence of this section, we have to explain structure or architecture in the `Examples` section itself.

Any thoughts in this regard?